# @Preauthorize in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, spring-security

I'm writting my application using GWT. There're two roles (ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN) in my app. ROLE_ADMIN has access to some handler

```java
@Service
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public class GetAuditDataListHandler extends AbstractActionHandler<GetAuditDataListAction, GetAuditDataListResult> {
// Code here
}
```

When I try to access under ROLE_USER I want to show dialogbox ("Access denied!"). But it returns *500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details*

```java
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
com.test.web.main.api.client.AuthRemoteServiceProxy$1.onResponseReceived(AuthRemoteServiceProxy.java:74)
com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will be checking the security roles and throwing an exception before executing the handler.

You would normally be able to catch this exception in the client onFailure() method of the Request but the exception thrown may not be serialisable or most likely not available to the GWT client side code and cannot be serialised - leading to the error.

It looks like you are using the gwt-dispatch library? I haven't used this for some time but you can override the `SpringSecureDispatchServlet` and add your own implementation of the `doUnexpectedFailure(Throwable e)` method. In there you could check the exception to see if it is a Spring security exception and instead of calling `RPCServletUtils.writeResponseForUnexpectedFailure(...)` that returns a status code of 500 implement your own that returns a more suitable error code (401, or 403).

Comment: Yes, I'm using gwt-dispatch. I've found that org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException is thrown to com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet#doUnexpectedFailure. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I haven't tried this and am not sure if it is the best approach but something like this should be workable.

Comment: Where I would to place overrided SpringSecureDispatchServlet? I can't find SpringSecureDispatchServlet.

Comment: You may be using `SpringStandardDispatchServlet`. Either way you are probably referencing it in your web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add a Servlet Filter to catch this particular exception and turn it into the HTTP response you would like?